# How turn on light mode for single app (Safari) on Big Sur 11.5.1

Tags: safari, big-sur, defaults, dark-mode

MacOS version is 11.5.1. In system preferences a dark appearance is selected. I want to apply a light appearance mode only to Safari. I did

```
defaults write com.apple.Safari NSRequiresAquaSystemAppearance -bool Yes
```

but it had no effect. Why that defaults setting may not work and what should I try to do to apply the light appearance mode only to Safari?

Comment: Are you seeing "Could not write domain" error? If yes, then you need to grant your terminal app "Full Disk Access" rights. See [this answer](https://www.reddit.com/r/MacOS/comments/pezo5s/comment/kbvqrt7/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) on Reddit for the details.